# Removing Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

As it says in the title. I want to get rid of this useless application ubuntu one. I've removed the application files from the software centre, but the icon is still shown.

[image]

Answer (score 81):

Open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
killall ubuntuone-login ubuntuone-preferences ubuntuone-syncdaemon

sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone

rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone

rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone

mv ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/UbuntuOne_old/``
```

(source: [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu-one/)) - Support pages no longer exist.

And then just to make sure.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntuone-*`

(Note for Ubuntu 14.*: Please refer to [iheggie](https://askubuntu.com/users/264474/iheggie)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454216/229676) to avoid the removal of the Ubuntu Desktop.)

**Edit:** The reason for this method over more simple methods is to ensure that the configurations, cache and any other preferences do not remain on your system; if we've learnt anything from Windows it's that prefetch is more than enough to slow a system down, it's good practise to clear your system now then to forget what needs to be cleaned later.

Comment: I think you forgot the nautilus bookmark.

Comment: Good stuff! Highly useful now that Ubuntu One has shut down and the referenced webpage is no longer available.

Comment: That is a shame, I wouldn't go as far to say that Ubuntu One was necessary or a large part of my Linux experiences (otherwise I would never have researched how to remove it), but it was still a useful service for many.

Comment: This command will keep only ubuntuone-client-data required by ubuntu-desktop (Ubuntu 14.04): `sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntuone-control-panel* deja-dup-backend-ubuntuone libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 python-ubuntuone-* rhythmbox-ubuntuone`

Comment: direct purge worked fine on 14.10, nothing happened with ubuntu-desktop though! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Of course, you can remove Ubuntu One (U1) either via the Software Centre (as mentioned in other answer) or through the terminal using:

`sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-*`

This will remove the U1 application along with the various U1 plugins for things like rhythmbox, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Under ubuntu trusty 14.04, I used @cossacksman's answer, except I removed the packages one by one using synaptic. I had to leave `ubuntuone-client-data` installed as both apt and synaptic wanted to remove `ubuntu-desktop` as well.

Comment: Indeed, how to remove all ubuntuone packages without removing ubuntu-desktop ? What happens if we remove ubuntu-desktop ?

Comment: Good work, also, [**here**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-desktop) is a link to the **ubuntu-desktop** package, it will list the many things which depend upon it being installed and consequently will cease to work if it is removed.

Answer (score -1):

Ok got my solution, remove Ubuntu One with Software Centrer, then remove Ubuntu One Music Store. Now reboot and no more annoying cloud icon.

Comment: Didn't work for me.