# Remove Ubuntu One Music App from Dash

Tags: unity, 13.10, ubuntu-one, unity-dash, music

Is there any way for me to remove the Ubuntu One Music App in Ubuntu 13.10? It's really annoying because I'm never going to use it and it always appears when I try do an app search in the dash. I had a similar problem the with Amazon app and I was able to find the following command to remove it, which worked perfectly:

sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop

I imagine I can do the exact same thing by substituting ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop with whatever the path is to ubuntu one music. However, I have no idea what that would be.

Comment: Check this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/309122/removing-ubuntu-one

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on it and simply choosing the `Unlock from Launcher` option in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but try doing `sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications/`, then looking for Ubuntu One Music and moving it to another folder (in case you need to access it), maybe move it to `/opt/`?

To do this: `sudo mv /usr/share/applications/UbuntuOneMusiconeubuntucom.desktop /opt`